# Which restricted-extras package for Ubuntu GNOME 17.04?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

There does not appear to be a `*buntu-restricted-extras` package for Ubuntu GNOME.

What is the correct way to install the various media codecs, etc?

Comment: is the Multiverse repository enabled in your system?  If not, it needs to be enabled then you can find the ubuntu-restricted-extras package.

Comment: Yes it is. I can find `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, `kubuntu-restricted-extras`, `lubuntu-restricted-extras`, and `xubuntu-restricted-extras`, but not `ubuntu-gnome-restricted-extras`.

Comment: Not every variant has their own restricted extras package.  Start with `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and see if that works for you - if all works well then you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

"ubuntu-restricted-extras" is part of "multiverse" section, If you can't get it using apt, first we must enable "Multiverse".

I would add:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
```

to:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

then:

```
sudo apt update
```

Now it should be available to you.

---

Which one?

Here is what's available to me:

```
$ apt search --names-only -- -restricted-extras

kubuntu-restricted-extras/zesty 65 amd64
  Commonly used media codecs and fonts for Kubuntu

lubuntu-restricted-extras/zesty 65 amd64
  Commonly used media codecs and fonts for Lubuntu

ubuntu-restricted-extras/zesty 65 amd64
  Commonly used media codecs and fonts for Ubuntu

xubuntu-restricted-extras/zesty 65 amd64
  Commonly used media codecs and fonts for Xubuntu
```

I suggest using "ubuntu-restricted-extra" for Ubuntu gnome over the other packages, most of their content are similar however cause many stuff within Unity and Gnome are close to each other I think it would be the best choice you've got.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **ubuntu-restricted-extras**.

The only reason there are a few different versions is because some Ubuntu desktop flavors had unique requirements. *kubuntu-restricted-extras* add some support for KDE. Lubuntu originally did not want to include PulseAudio. And in Ubuntu 17.10+, *xubuntu-restricted-extras* just points to *ubuntu-restricted-extras*.